# Setup Cloudera Quickstart behind proxy

Tags: cloudera, cloudera-manager

I cannot get the quickstart working when running behind proxy in my organisation (when running at home it works fine so Im assuming its the firewall or more likely proxy).

The quickstart Hue loads but complains that oozie, Impala, Hbase (the list goes on...) have problems.  For example Hbase server "cannot connect to localhost:9000".

It lists a location in /var/ for configuration but this location cannot be accessed due to permissions.  I have also tried setting the proxies which allow the sandbox to connect to internet but this causes the hue to not start at all but rather hang "loading".  I have also tried with both NAT and bridged adapters

Please help

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create a ssh tunnel, used it to go through a firewall on an actual cluster to connect to HUE.

To do so:

```
ssh -L 9000:127.0.0.1:9000 [ip_of_hue_host]
```

Then in your web browser settings change the proxy on 127.0.0.1, port 9000.

If you are on windows, you can use putty or plink to do so, if you are on Linux, you just need a term most likely ! :)